# Update directive view when attribute value is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have some 10 directives using isolate scopes. They all bind to a parameter named `size`. So I plan to create a common directive `suiCommon` and include this directive inside all 10 directives. So that I do not need to repeat `scope: { size: '@' }` for all 10 directives.

In my current solution [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ku2gxa09/2/), the parameter is passed correctly into the directive. However, when the value is changed outside, the value in the directive is not changed and applied.

My common directive is:

```
angular.module('sui.common', [])
    .directive('suiCommon', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, iElement) {
            var $parentElement = iElement.parent();
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.vm.size = $parentElement.attr('size');
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

One of my 10 directives are like:

```
angular.module('sui.rating', ['sui.common'])
    .directive('suiRating', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        template:
            '<div sui-common class="ui {{vm.size}} rating sui-rating">Content</div>',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {}]
    };
}]);
```

Here is HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="JoyCtrl as vm">
    <div ng-click="vm.setSize()">Click to change size</div>
    <div sui-rating size="{{vm.size}}"></div>
</div>
```

Now when the `size` is changed to `small` through `ng-click`, the value inside the directive is not changed. In my understanding, `ng-click` will trigger a `$scope.$apply`, which will re-render the directive `suiCommon`. Seems I am wrong...

Could anybody please explain the reason? How to fix it? Or is there any better solution?

Comment: Just an opinion, but i feel that having "scope: { size: '@' }" in each directive would be more clear and maintainable than creating a directive that inject the parameter into some other directives. It would be harder to understand what is happening into your directives

Comment: @Okazari thank you for your suggestions. I guess there is some better way to achieve that. And will be waiting for some more opinions.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using $cacheFactory to store the size in a single place and then just retrieve it in each directive.

Do something like this when you create your main module:

```
.factory('appCache', function ($cacheFactory) {
    var results = $cacheFactory('CurrentOrderCache');
    return results;
})
```

Then in suiCommon use:

```
appCache.put('suiCommonSize',10)
```

and in the other directives use:

```
appCache.get('suiCommonSize')
```

I should add that you'll also have to inject appCache everywhere you want to reference it.

Comment: It doesn't really need $cacheFactory in this case, appCache can just be an empty object, but yes, a service for storing common data is ok.